# Mantis SOAP mc_issue_update

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

im trying to manipulate mantis bt with soap api via nusoap

here is code example im trying to update and issue

```
<?php
require_once('nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php');
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

$WSDL_POINT = "http://test_test_test/api/soap/mantisconnect.php";
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$issue_id = 500;
$project_id = 5;


$params_update = array (
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
    'issueId ' => $issue_id,
    'issue' => array (
        'id' => 3890500,
        'summary' => 'test test test',
        'project'=>array('id'=>$project_id),
        'status' => array (
            'id' => 10,
            'name' => 'resolved'
            ),
    )
);


$client = new nusoap_client($WSDL_POINT, false);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->decode_utf8 = false;

$result = $client->call('mc_issue_update', $params_update, 'http://test_test_test/api/soap/mantisconnect.php', 'testtest');



echo "<pre>";
print_r ($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Running my script results in empty array response, and issue wasnt updated, at the same time i'm having no problems with mc_issue_get, im getting response array with issue data.

Please help me find out whats wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved during debug output, using code:

echo "Request:\n";
echo $client->request."\n\n\n";

echo "Response:\n";
echo $client->response."\n";

description and summary fields in issue array are must have during query.